# JPanel not receiving Mouse events on mac

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel in a JFrame.  I want the panel to receive mouse events but they go to the JFrame instead when run on macOS.  I tried requesting focus and it didn't help

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelInFrame extends JPanel {

    public PanelInFrame() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("panel click!");
            }
        });
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            PanelInFrame panel = new PanelInFrame();
            frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("frame click!");
                }
            });
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            panel.requestFocusInWindow();
        });
    }
}
```

I want it to report "panel click!".
When I run this on a Mac (macOs 10.14.5, Java 11.0.2) I only get "frame click" but on Linux I get "panel click"

On macOS:

```
mac $ javac PanelInFrame.java 
mac $ java PanelInFrame
frame click!
frame click!
frame click!
mac $ java --version
java 11.0.2 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
mac $ uname -a
Darwin gavin-mpb.lan 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro12,1 Darwin
```

On linux:

```
linux $ javac PanelInFrame.java 
linux $ java PanelInFrame 
panel click!
panel click!
panel click!
linux $ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
linux $ uname -a
Linux hostname 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I stated focus doesn't matter on my platform. Maybe it does on your platform Your updated version doesn't use setFocusable(true) and requestFocusInWindow() on the panel AFTER the frame is visible, to see if this makes a different on your platform.

Comment: @camickr I just tried that and it doesn't help

Comment: Again, post what you tried. We need to make sure you invoke the methods in the proper place. I don't have a Mac so I can't test anything. Maybe you do need the setRequestFocusEnabled(true) on a Mac, I can only provide information on how it works on my platform, so I have no other suggestions.

Comment: @camickr I did, see above

Comment: Weirdly, it works on apple jdk6, but fails on oracle or openjdk on mac

Comment: It fixed itself when I rebooted my computer, so probably something that was wrong with my computer specifically...

Comment: So I guess my answer was correct? Focus does not matter for MouseEvents. Did you remove the focus related code? Or is it indeed required?

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't seem to get it to be focused so mouse events are going to the frame instead.

Focus is only relevant for KeyEvents.

That is only components with focus can receive KeyEvents.

Focus does not matter for MouseEvents. When you click on a component, Swing will search for the first component in the parent/child hierarchy to find the component with a MouseListener.

When I run your code I see "panel click" indicating the MouseEvent is indeed going to the panel, not the frame.

```
    this.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    this.requestFocus();
    this.grabFocus();
```

Also, note that you can only request focus on a visible realized component, which basically means you request focus AFTER you pack() or use setVisible(true) on the frame.

The proper method to use is the `requestFocusInWindow()` method.

I don't believe the `setRequestFocusEnabled(true)` is required to set focus on a panel, only the `setFocusable(true)`.

Also note that all Swing components should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. See the `Frame Demo` example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for the better structure to your class to make sure the code executes on the `EDT`.

Also, the `pack()` should be done just be the `setVisible(...)` so methods like setRisizable(...) work properly.

Comment: Well, when I run it "panel click" does not get printed.

Comment: Could be a version/platform difference. I use JDK 8 on Windows 7. I also added extra info which may be applicable.

Comment: I edited my question to focus on not receiving mouse events and add example output.  I didn't see anything in your link about the EDT; what part actually needs to run on it?

Comment: All of it. Look at the code in the example. I took the time to read your question. Please take the time to look at the demo code I referred you to. You can also read the section from the Swing tutorial on `Concurrency` for more info about the EDT.

Comment: I tried putting all of main in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and it still has the same problem